# Catching SSLErrors within Tornado

Tags: python, ssl, tornado

I'm running Tornado 4.0.2 in a Python 2.7.5 virtualenv using SSL and a self-signed certificate and am the following SSLError is showing up repeatedly:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1419: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

A few questions follow:

1. I'm assuming these exceptions are due to clients freaking out about my self-signed certificate. Is this correct?
2. Assuming this is the case - I don't care about this exception, and I don't want to see it in the log. (It's an internal webserver - we're never going to pay for a CA. All connections are just going to have to be untrusted.) In an attempt to catch the exceptions myself, I've tried subclassing IOLoop as follows:

   ```
   class MyIOLoop(IOLoop):
       def handle_callback_exception(callback):
           print "Exception in callback", callback

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = Application(urls, compress_response = True)
       ioloop=MyIOLoop.instance()
       http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options={"certfile": "cert.pem", "keyfile": "key.pem" }, io_loop=ioloop )
       http_server.listen(8888)
       ioloop.start()
   ```

But this hasn't helped - I still get the full stack trace.

What do I need to do to handle (i.e. ignore) such exceptions myself? I've experimented with setting `cert_reqs" : ssl.CERT_NONE` in the ssl_options but that also hasn't helped.

3. Is there anything else I need to do - such as close the connection myself - when I've caught such an exception? If so, what, and how?

Answer (score 1):

I also [asked this question on the Tornado mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/MnNbTemU6ps), and got the following response:

> This error is coming from HTTP1ServerConnection, not IOLoop (I think
>   it's uncommon for errors to make it all the way up to the IOLoop these
>   days). You're correct that this means that a client has refused to
>   connect because it doesn't trust your certificate. It's arguably
>   useful to log something in this case (you'd want to know if this
>   started happening a lot), but it should be at most one line instead of
>   a full stack trace. It might also be better to treat it as more like
>   ECONNRESET and log nothing.
>
> We don't currently expose any useful ways to customize this logging,
>   but you have options in the logging module itself. You could attach a
>   Filter to the logger and block entries where exc_info[0] is SSLError
>   and exc_info[1] has the right error code, for example.

I ended up adding a filter to Tornado's logger as suggested. One slight snag was that `record.exc_info` was sometimes `None`, but in such situations I was able to get enough information out of `record.args` to decide if I want to filter it.

Comment: Interesting, but how did you add the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [helgridly's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26936729/320036): the error [can't be caught](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/MnNbTemU6ps), but you can [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) the logs.

1. Create a function that checks for the presence of an SSL error in a log record, and rejects certain such errors
2. Install it as a filter for the `tornado.general` logger

For example:

```
def ssl_log_filter(record):
    if record.exc_info is not None:
        e = record.exc_info[1]
    elif len(record.args) >= 3 and isinstance(record.args[2], Exception):
        e = record.args[2]
    else:
        e = None

    if isinstance(e, SSLEOFError):
        return False
    if isinstance(e, SSLError):
        if e.reason in {'NO_SHARED_CIPHER'}:
            return False

    return True


logging.getLogger('tornado.general').addFilter(ssl_log_filter)
```

The code above will only work for Python 3.2+. For older versions, subclass `Filter` instead.